# Using CMD Module with a Socket

Tags: python

I've been having a hard time getting the CMD module to use a socket for stdin. Here is what I have :

```
class Server(cmd.Cmd):
    use_rawinput = False 

    def __init__(self, port): 
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(("", port))
        f = self.sock.makefile(mode='rw') 
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self, stdin = f, stdout=sys.stdout) 


    def do_register(self, username):    
        print username
```

When I connect with the client and try the command `register user1`, I don't get anything on the server's console.

Comment: You should not that SOCK_DGRAM removes the concept of order. The packets can be received out of order, meaning that it probably doesn't make sense to be used as a file anyway.

Comment: I am forced to use SOCK_DGRAM because this is for an assignment for a class. The order doesn't really matter in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file returned by `makefile` will only work for `SOCK_STREAM` sockets. `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets have no notion of a continuous stream of bytes (only individual packets), and therefore cannot use `read` or `write`.

You should initialize the socket with `socket.SOCK_STREAM` instead of `socket.SOCK_DGRAM`.

Comment: It does in fact work. I figured out what the problem is. readline() was never returning because the packet from the client didn't have a newline in it. Adding \n to everything the client sends seems to work. However, I'm not sure now how to tell who the client is now.

Comment: I admit now that write() doesn't not make sense because you don't know where to send to, but read() and readline() do make sense.

Comment: You should really use `recv`/`recvfrom`.

Comment: I came up with a way to tell who the client is (ie ip and port) and can now reply to messages as well. 

Socket.makefile() and readline() are much more convenient for use with the Cmd module, because clients can just send their commands and the appropriate function gets called automatically, along with precmd and postcmd. If you use recv you need to call precmd, onecmd, and postcmd yourself.