# Storing Login Credentials for Command Line App

Tags: python, shell, ssh, authentication, terminal

I am writing a command line app in python using the `click` module that will SSH to Cisco network device and send configuration commands over the connection using the `netmiko` module. The problem I'm running into is that SSH-ing to the network device requires a hostname/IP, username, and password. I am trying to implement a way for a user of my script to login to a device once and keep the SSH connection open, allowing subcommands to be run without logging in each time. For example,

```
$ myapp ssh
hostname/IP: 10.10.110.10 
username: user
password: ********

Connected to device 10.10.101.10

$ myapp command1
log output

$ myapp --option command2
log output

$ myapp disconnect
closing connection to 10.10.101.10
```

How would I go about storing/handling credentials to allow this functionality in my cli? I have seen recommendations of caching or OAuth in researching this issue, but I'm still not sure how to implement this or what the recommended and safe way to do this is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are attempting something like this.

```
$ myapp ssh -u user -p password
(myapp) command1
(myapp) command2
(myapp) disconnect
$
```

Python has a standard library module cmd that may help:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html

Comment: This is how my app is implemented now. I want to be able to call each command separately, though.

Comment: Perhaps listen on a socket and create a new command like "myapp send" that would send over the same socket?  This question looks similar.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739539/using-cmd-module-with-a-socket

Comment: Logins and passwords are sensitive information. I suggest you have a look at the `keyring` package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring that works on OSX, Linux and Windows Credential Vault.